# How do you write a compelling job listing for UX

Tags: jobs, hiring

I'm looking to hire another person for my team so I've been researching job sites that list open [UX/design positions](http://uxdesignjobs.net/). I thought it would be a good idea to familiarize myself with the language employers are using.

I've got to be honest: *95% of them are total shit.* Nearly all of them sound like they were written by the HR person after Googling for the most generic list of attributes ever assembled.

Since I've come to trust this community's opinion more than the average site, **what types of techniques and language would you use to convince the most talented UX'ers to come work for you?**

Comment: Somewhat related: this just popped up on 37signals job board today. I think Jason himself started it: http://jobs.37signals.com/jobs/7759

Comment: You answered the question. YOU write it. NOT HR.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about being a usability designer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, as a recent job applicant, thank you for caring enough to edit your ad. I was very frustrated with the multitude of poor job descriptions. I couldn't believe the amount of effort they wanted from the applicant, when the company couldn't be bothered to list real details, let alone spell check. As someone who builds a cover letter from the job ad, if you give me nothing to work with I can only do so much.

Based on my recent job search I can tell you somethings based off my experience.

- Everybody wants a "rockstar" that doesn't make you interesting. I cringe when I see it now.
- Keep it short and relevant.
- I was always most interested in which phase of the UX cycle most of the work is expected.
- If there is something special about this UX job over similar job (like: must be able to use Linux, or will primarily be doing remote testing) make sure that it is listed first.
- Anything that will give a sense of the team that the applicant will be working with. (ex. we're dog people, or Expect to discuss tv show X every Monday morning)

Keep in mind that by the time they are reading your ad the applicant is looking for something that stands out about the team or the company.

Comment: Since you brought up the rockstar comment, my opinion from a while ago: http://mnteractive.com/archive/hire-me-im-a-rock-star-woooo-rock-on

Comment: Very good DA...

Answer (score 6):

From my experience, these are the things that I would love to hear mentioned in a job posting that are often not:

- a realistic list of responsibilities (rather than the "Must know everything about the IT industry, software industry, and graphic design/marketing industries" silliness)
- an idea of pay/seniority level. In our industry, it can be hard to gauge what level of employee a company wants to bring in. Is it entry level? Senior 10+ years experience? Doesn't matter?
- Some descriptions of the work environment and culture at your company.

Answer (score 3):

Agreed Kyle.

As someone pointed out a while back the problem with the internet is that it provides too much space at no cost.

When you had to pay per word for an ad in a newspaper every word really had to count.

A good job ad ***isn't*** just a great long line of bullet points from an HR jobspec - a good ad is selling the job as well as acting as a filter.

And a good ad is also selling your company.  Done well its general PR.

(And somewhere I've got a useful job ad writing checklist which I currently can't find - There's a shortened version here:

http://london-ia-jobs.ning.com/notes/Guidelines_for_Job_Posting)

UPDATE: Having played with search terms in google, 'how to write a job advert' finds some useful links.

There are some useful suggestions on the end of this:

http://www.brenthodgson.com/marketing-case-studies/copywriting-and-split-testing-job-ads.php[link text](http://www.brenthodgson.com/marketing-case-studies/copywriting-and-split-testing-job-ads.php)

Answer (score 2):

Good article on this

### 5 Steps to an Uber user experience job description

http://www.usefulusability.com/5-steps-to-an-uber-user-experience-job-description/